# JToken.explicit operator bool cannot call operator or accessor directly

Tags: json.net, explicit

```
if (JToken.op_Explicit(apiConfig["finjVersion"]) < JToken.op_Explicit(latestData["finjVersion"]))
{
 ...
}
```

***Error:** JToken.explicit operator bool(JToken)': cannot call operator or accessor directly*

I tried searching it in Newtonsoft's website or Microsoft and found nothing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a full [mcve], specifically a sample of the JSON you are parsing that includes the `"finjVersion"` property.  Also, can you confirm that you writing in [tag:c#]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to invoke one of the [explicit conversion operators](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit.htm) of [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jtoken.htm) to convert a JSON property value to a .NET primitive.  In order to use these operators, you must use the [explicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) syntax of c# to cast the value to the required primitive type.  You must also choose an appropriate .NET [primitive type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types) to which to cast that corresponds to the JSON property value.

E.g. if the value of `"finjVersion"` is some integer such as `"finjVersion" : 1` you should do:

```
if ((long)apiConfig["finjVersion"] < (long)latestData["finjVersion"])
{
    //...
}
```

Demo #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7fxmg0).

If the value of `"finjVersion"` does not correspond to a .NET primitive, rather than casting you must use [`ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm) to deserialize to the required type. E.g. if `"finjVersion"` looks like `"finjVersion":"1.1.2.0"`, you could deserialize to [`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-7.0) like so:

```
if (apiConfig["finjVersion"].ToObject<Version>() < latestData["finjVersion"].ToObject<Version>())
{
    //...
}
```

Demo #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/poUbzw).

Comment: The (JToken) worked